# Can the Lie group structure be recovered from the geometry of an invariant metric?

Tags: lie-groups, riemannian-geometry

Is there a  manifold $M$  with two non isomorphic Lie  group  structures $G_{1}$ and $G_{2}$, and two left invariant metrics $g_{1}$  and $g_{2}$, respectively such that $(M,g_{1})$ is isometric to  $(M, g_{2})$?

Comment: This is possible even in dimension $2$ if one allows indefinite-signature metrics: For the affine group $\Bbb R \rtimes \Bbb R$ (which is diffeomorphic to $\Bbb R^2$), in a basis $(E_1, E_2)$ of the Lie algebra such that $[E_1, E_2] = E_2$ any metric of the form $a (e^1)^2 + 2 b e^1 e^2$, $b \neq 0$, is flat, and hence isometric to (any) left-invariant signature $(1, 1)$ metric on $(\Bbb R^2, +)$. I do not know offhand about the Riemannian case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you have an example in the Riemannian case. Take $M=\mathbb{R}^3$ as smooth manifold. Then $M$ is diffeomorphic to the the universal covering of the Lie group $E(2)$ of rigid motions of the Euclidean $2$-space.
So we can consider $M$ with two different non isomorphic Lie group structure. Namely, the above one and the obvious one as $3$-dimensional abelian group.
By Corollary 4.8 at page 309 in Milnor's [paper](http://ac.els-cdn.com/S0001870876800023/1-s2.0-S0001870876800023-main.pdf?_tid=0be928c8-2257-11e5-bd91-00000aab0f6c&acdnat=1436019476_ed07e6d8f05232398d2d49b545f8bcde), there is a flat metric $g$ on $E(2)$. So $(M,g)$ and $(M,g_0)$ are isometric, where $g_0$ is the standard flat metric but $E(2)$ and $\mathbb{R}^3$ regarded as Lie groups are not isomorphic.